# Schedule getstream.io Notification / Activity for future date or time

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

When you POST an activity to a feed on getstream, the activity is immediately returned when you GET that feed. Is there any way to schedule an activity such that you set a future date, and the activity is not returned by the GET request until after that future date has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, you can only do this client side (eg. filter activities `activity.visible_at < now`) or by scheduling the POST request in the future.